# Alter URL variable of asp script

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

The script currently adds the entire url (including /default.html), and what I am trying to change is the last part of the url. I would like to remove the default.html (essentially the file name part of the url).

So basically this part of the code i would like to change is this:

```
if matches = 1 Then
    Response.Redirect( urlLink ) //Would like to add new code here to change url that is passed
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim url
url = Mid(urlLink, 1, InStrRev(urlLink, "/"))
```

To check there is in fact a "/" character in your urlLink variable, use this:

```
If InStr(urlLink, "/") > -1 Then
    Dim url
    url = Mid(urlLink, 1, InStrRev(urlLink, "/"))
End If
```

This will take the original Url, and read until it finds the last "/" character.

Comment: What is the error? You've got to make sure there is a "/" in the urlLink variable, or it will crash.

Comment: Are you still getting an error? My code should work. Wrap your code in a try/catch, and tell me the error you are getting :)

Comment: Look at my code again. Try without adding "As String" that worked for me. It's been a long time since I last coded asp classic. :p

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28532/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-jrags87)